# Moving a member of a List to the Front of the List

Tags: c#, .net

How would one create a method that takes an integer `i`, and move the member of a `List<T>` at index `i` from its current position to the front of the list?

Comment: you are trying to sort it, aren't you?

Comment: would i need to sort it to do that? i just want to move the ONE member at index i, to the front of the list.. don't need to move the rest

Answer (score 34):

The [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=VS.90).aspx) class doesn't offer such a method, but you can write an extension method that gets the item, removes it and finally re-inserts it:

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    static void MoveItemAtIndexToFront<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
    {
        T item = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        list.Insert(0, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: the header for the method is supposed to be like this:
public void MoveToFront(int i)

Comment: Okay, since you _know_ the signature I'm boldly claiming that this is homework. Tag it as that next time.

Comment: @Shonna: the method needs a reference to the list. You need to pass that in or change my code to access the list in a different way which should be simple enough.

Comment: @dtb You could match that header if you subclassed `List<T>` :-p

Answer (score 16):

Any of the 3 answers so far do the trick, but instead of doing a RemoveAt and a Insert operation, I would suggest moving each item one place to the right from the desired positions left, to the beginning of the list. That way you avoid moving the items placed at the right of the item moved.

This is a modification of @dtb's answer.

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    static void MoveItemAtIndexToFront<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
    {
        T item = list[index];
        for (int i = index; i > 0; i--)
            list[i] = list[i - 1];
        list[0] = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: For an extension method, this would make more sense as it's faster on average than dtb's method.

Comment: @Groo Is it always faster, even for larger lists?

Comment: @CodeBlend: yes, for larger lists the difference would be more pronounced, although I cannot claim you will notice any difference in practice. Theoretically, this method and dtb's are both `O(n)`, but in dtb's answer `list.RemoveAt` will first remove the item and then copy all following items one place backwards, and then `list.Insert(0, item)` will again insert the item at index `0` and then copy all items forward by 1 position. Fede's method, on the other hand, only does a single sweep backwards (number of swaps equal to `index`).

Answer (score 5):

```
var l = new List<DataItem>();
var temp = l[index];
l.RemoveAt(index);
l.Insert(0, temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    static List<int> idList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };

    private static void moveListItem(int index)
    {
        int getIndex = 0;

        foreach (int item in idList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Before Id List Value - {0} ,Index - {1} ", item.ToString(), getIndex);
            getIndex++;
        }

        int value = idList[index];
        idList.RemoveAt(index);
        idList.Insert(0, value);

        Console.WriteLine();

        getIndex = 0;
        foreach (int item in idList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" After Id List Value - {0} ,Index - {1} ", item.ToString(), getIndex);
            getIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of beating a dead horse:

Wouldn't a LinkedList be more suited for this?
Although you would loose the random access functionality, inserting elements at the beginning of the List would be much simpler (.AddFirst) and a lot more efficient.